# Error during an attempt to import generated js module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Babel keep changing, what's the basic configuration of babelrc?

I have this in my .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
    "plugins": [
        ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }]
      ]
}
```

And the transpiled code of this

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h2>test</h2>
  }
}
```

Got error of `React.createElement: type is invalid — expected a string` I'm on react `"react": "^15.6.1"`

https://github.com/thian4/webpack-problem

I do `npm run build-lib` in my demo project.

Comment: what version babel are use?

Comment: how do you transpile code?

Comment: @hendrathings I've included my demo project demo

Comment: @havenchyk I'm using webpack, I've include my demo

Comment: @SharonChai are you sure, repo is correct? I don't see webpack there, only parcel

Comment: @SharonChai your demo doesn't have webpack config

Comment: @SharonChai everything works fine, I see ```_createClass(Test, [{
    key: 'render',
    value: function render() {
      return _react2.default.createElement(
        'h1',
        null,
        'Test'
      );
    }
  }]);
``` inside `lib/test.js`

Comment: @havenchyk you haven't try see the result on browser. Do `npm start` and visit http://localhost:3000

Comment: found the solution, have to include `libraryTarget: "umd"` in webpack.prod.js

Comment: @SharonChai the problem was in your `test.js` file that was generated by `build-lib`, you didn't export that lib, but in general your idea is wrong because you have everything in code base and you don't need to rely on generated flie from `./lib` folder in dev mode

Comment: so, babel config is correct, so the problem in your webpack config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in your wrong usage of webpack and doesn't relate to `baberlc` file or configuration.

1) with `npm run build-lib` you build a file in `lib` folder, but without real export, so `umd` target is a solution

2) but 1) is a wrong approach because you build the same code base into another file and import it in development mode

Comment: I know the answer, but I don't know why I need to use umd.

Comment: @SharonChai because you rely on a module that is built with `npm run build-lib` which doesn't have default export afaik

Comment: Default export afaik means? this is the src that get bundled with `npm run build-lib` : `export default class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Test</h1>
  }
}`